# netsh interface ipv4 add address KtConnectTunnel 241.254.242.142 255.255.0.0 The parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows, netsh, tun

I have a tun virtual network card
I execute this command on window11：
netsh interface ipv4 add address KtConnectTunnel   241.254.242.142 255.255.0.0
But it reported an error：The parameter is incorrect
It cannot be added between 241.255.0.0 and 255.0.0.0, but others can be added
for example：
netsh interface ipv4 add address KtConnectTunnel 172.*.*.* 255.255.0.0
This command used to be fine for a long time, but suddenly an error was reported

I want to know why and successfully execute this command.